# The program is: Please enter a 3 digits number: 635 The permutations are: 635, 653, 365, 356, 563, 536

Tags: python, list, integer, concatenation, typeerror

```
def permutation_generate(lst):
    if len(lst)== 0:
        return []
    
    if len(lst)==1:
        return [1]
    
    l =[]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]
        
        remLst= lst[:i]+ lst[i+1:]
        for p in permutation_generate(remLst):
            l.append([m]+p)
        return l
    
data= list(input("Please enter a 3 digits number:\n"))
print("The permutations are:")
for p in permutation_generate(data):
    print(*p,sep='', end="")
```

#TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
#What is the solution of the error?

Comment: What is your question/issue? You forgot to add it to your question

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: The len of your list will always be 1 as you are not splitting the string but making a list of string that is ['635'] which will always return [1]. But the main problem is coming in the for p in permutation_generate(remLst) l.append([m]+p) here m is a lit while p is integer as p is the value inside the list which is 1 and you can't add a list and an integer. Overall the whole function is flawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 13 your function `permutation_generate(remLst)` returns a list `[1]`
and you start iterating over it in a `for` loop. So p is `1` of type `int`
thats why on line 14 you get the error trying to concatenate [m]+int won't work. [m]+[p] would work.

And for your task take a look at itertools module of python standard library